# Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers. (Java)

Tags: java

I am having a bit of trouble solving Project Euler question 4. I am inexperienced in programming and didn't really understand other answers. I managed to write a code that prints all six-digits palindromes. How do I find the largest palindrome made from the multiplying of two 3-digit numbers?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 998001;
        int count=0;
        int temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6;
        int temp;
        int num1=999;
        int num2=100;
        for (int i = 100000; i <= 998001; i++) {
            num=998001-count;
            temp=num;
            temp1=temp%10;
            temp=temp/10;
            temp2=temp%10;
            temp=temp/10;
            temp3=temp%10;
            temp=temp/10;
            temp4=temp%10;
            temp=temp/10;
            temp5=temp%10;
            temp=temp/10;
            temp6=temp%10;
            temp=temp/10;

            if (temp1==temp6 && temp5==temp2 && temp3==temp4) {
                System.out.println(num);
            }
            count=count+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a list of numbers, any numbers, do you know how to find the largest one?

Comment: I do. By using int Max I can compare the numbers to Max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method which loops over all numbers from 1-999 and multiplies them with all possible numbers from 1-999. You will need to define a method `isPalindrome(int)` that will check if a given int is a palindrome.

```
//save the largest number
int largest = 0;

//loop over every possible product of numbers from 100-999
for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
 for (int j = i; j >= 100; j--) {
  int curr = i * j;

  //if the current number is a palindrome and is greater than the last found largest
  if (isPalindrome(curr) && curr > largest) {

   //save it as the new largest found number
   largest = curr;
  }
 }
}
```

The `isPalindrome` method might look like this:

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(Integer possible) {
    String toStr = possible.toString();
    int len = toStr.length();
    if (len % 2 == 1) {
        len = len - 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        if (toStr.charAt(i) != toStr.charAt(toStr.length() - (1 + i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Euler wants the largest palindrome, so it is probably better to run the loops downwards from 999 to 100: `for (i = 999; i > 99; i--)`  The code the OP showed can easily be reworked to make the `isPalindrome()` method.

Comment: You can assume the minimum is `100` as `1` is one digit. You could also start at the top (largest numbers) and stop the inner loop when you have a product smaller than the best you have already. Also you can assume `j >= i`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you're right, edited to reflect that improvement.

Comment: I think you mean `for (int j = 999; j >= i; j--) {`

Comment: Or even `int min = largest / i; for (int j = 999; j >= i && j >= min; j--)` once you have a solution there is no point search for values whose product can't be largest. Also once you find the largest for a value of `i` you can break and try another `i`

Comment: I appreciate the help but I don't understand the code. Perhaps I need more concrete knowledge of the basics of Java.

Comment: @Carebear What don't you understand?

Comment: @Carebear I added some comments that hopefully make it more clear

Comment: Thank you. Your comments made me understand it much better.

Comment: @Carebear no problem. If it helped please upvote and accept =]

Answer (score 0):

for 3 digits loop can be started from 100 to 1000(exclusive).

You can try this ::

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
for(int i=100; i<1000; i++){
    for(int j=100; j<1000; j++){
        String mul = String.valueOf(i*j);
        if(isPalindrome(mul)){
            num1 = i;
            num2 = j;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(num1*num2);
```

Implement palindrome method as :

```
boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    String strRev = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
    return str.equals(strRev);
}
```

This works good but take this as reference and improve as needed
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to check `PALINDROME`-ness of a number without converting it to a `String`.

```
bool checkPalindrome(int n)
{
    int num = n;
    int s = 0;
    while(num!=0)
    {
      s = s*10 + (num%10);
      num = num/10;
    }
    if(s==n)
      return true;
    return false;
}
```

As you can see that if `n` = `120`, the reverse is calculated as `s` = `21` instead of `021`, but that is fine, keeping in mind that a palindrome number won't end in `0`, because if it does, then it would have to begin with `0` which makes it an invalid number!!!!

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the same question...

It is way more easier to create a list, that we know will be filled from smallest to the largest, because counter numbers only rize...

```
        List<Integer> palindrome = new ArrayList<>(); // create integer list

    for ( int i = 900; i<999; i++){
        for ( int j = 900; j < 950; j++){
            // both counter numbers are bigger than 900
            // because there will those two int's be, logically
            String newMul = String.valueOf(i * j);  // make it string for palindrome comparation
            String strRev = new StringBuilder(newMul).reverse().toString(); // rotate previous string
                                                                            // for palindrome comparation 
            if(newMul.equals(strRev)){  //if its equal
            palindrome.add(i * j);      //will put multiplication result of i and j into list
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(palindrome.get(palindrome.size()-1)); // last number in list is the 
}                                                            // biggest so lets print it out
```

Basicly, you just need little casting to se if it is a palindrome, but if it is, just multiply i and j to put them into list... It will loop for a long time, but that way you checked all the numbers bigger than 900 for the biggest palindrome...

Hope I helped...